# Steeltoe ASP.NET Core CloudFoundryJwtBearer breaking change?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, steeltoe

I was trying to update my ASP.NET Core (.NET 6) Web API to use Steeltoe 3.x (it currently uses 2.1.1), but I've run into a breaking problem with JWT authorization. After some checking, the same problem occurs when updating to 2.5.5.

In my project I have this code:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.WebHost.UseCloudFoundryHosting().AddCloudFoundry();
//other code
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCloudFoundryJwtBearer(builder.Configuration);
```

It works fine

I tried to change it to this code, when updating to Steeltoe 3.2.2:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.WebHost.UseCloudHosting().AddCloudFoundryConfiguration();
//other code
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCloudFoundryJwtBearer(builder.Configuration);
```

But it didn't work, there were no claims in the `AuthorizationContext`
Then I tried to use the first code, but using Steeltoe 2.5.5, but encountered the same problem.

Is there some additional configuration required in the newer versions of Steeltoe?

Comment: There isn't supposed to be any additional config required, and security packages haven't needed to change a whole lot in the last several years, but there was some refactoring done after 2.1.1. Would you mind testing 2.2.0 to see how that works?

Comment: @Tim I checked, 2.2.0 doesn't work either

Comment: Terribly sorry I've taken so long to get to this, have you resolved the issue? I've made some progress updating the relevant [Steeltoe samples](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/tree/security-refresh/Security) to the minimal API style and those appear to be functioning as expected with no framework changes

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I apologize, now I have updated the code.

In Steeltoe 3.x, you could try the code below.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.WebHost.UseCloudHosting().AddCloudFoundryConfiguration();

//other code

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
        options.Authority = "https://your-authorization-server-url";;
        options.Audience = "your-api-or-resource-name";
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false
        };
});
```

Comment: I get `'CloudFoundryDefaults' does not contain a definition for 'Authority'`. I also checked Steeltoe's Github, and I don't see `Authority` property in the `CloudFoundryDefaults` class either

Comment: Hi @JohnDiGriz, I have updated the code, if there are some error message, pls let me know.